# Since rails is usually run in its own process in a single threaded manner, do you need a conn pool?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, connection-pooling, passenger, thin

From what I understand, it is common practice to run multiple processes via thin/phusion to support concurrency with Rails.  Meaning that if you want to to mimick 30 threads, you would have to spawn 30 seperate rails processes running your app.

If the above is correct, does ActiveRecord then support connection pooling or is there only a single connection to mysql?  It doesn't make sense to even require more than one connection since each rails process is never serving more than a single request right?

Answer (score 1):

An Nginx/Unicorn stack handles this sort of issue quite elegantly, and hides the implementation of the DB connection pool.

Read more here: https://github.com/blog/517-unicorn